# JPA Hibernate Lazy load collection in a self relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to lazily load the ingredients of a product in a self relationship. A product can have zero or more ingredients. The relationship is stored in the `ProductComposition` entity.
These are my entities:

Product

```
@Entity(name = Product.TABLE_NAME)
//@NamedEntityGraph(name = "graph.Product.ingredients", attributeNodes = //@NamedAttributeNode("ingredients"))
public class Product {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Product";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long idProduct;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE}, mappedBy = "product")
    private List<OrderDetail> orders;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "ingredient", orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<ProductComposition> ingredients;
```

ProductComposition

```
@Entity(name = ProductComposition.TABLE_NAME)
@IdClass(ProductCompositionId.class)
public class ProductComposition {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "ProductComposition";

    @Id
    @ManyToOne //(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "PrincipalProductID")
    private Product principalProduct;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne //(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "IngredientID")
    private Product ingredient;

    private int quantity;
```

ProductCompositionId

```
class ProductCompositionId implements Serializable{

private long principalProduct;

private long ingredient;
```

In the method `get` of my Dao I've tried different things:

Fetching with a `CriteriaQuery` the ingredients and then set them to the product

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<ProductComposition> q = cb.createQuery(ProductComposition.class);
Root<ProductComposition> product = q.from(ProductComposition.class);
product.fetch("principalProduct", JoinType.LEFT);
q.select(product).where(cb.equal(product.get("principalProduct"), id));     
List<ProductComposition> ingredients = entityManager.createQuery(q).getResultList();
Product p = entityManager.find(Product.class, id);
p.setIngredients(ingredients);
```

Using an `Entity Graph`

```
EntityGraph<Product> graph = (EntityGraph<Product>) entityManager.getEntityGraph("graph.Product.ingredients");
Map<String, Object> ingredients = new HashMap<>();
ingredients.put("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", graph);
Product p = entityManager.find(entityClass, id, ingredients);
```

Calling the method `initialize`

```
p = productDao.get(p.getIdProduct()); //the get here just calls entityManager.find(Product.class, id)
Hibernate.initialize(p.getIngredients());
System.out.println("Ingredients size: "+p.getIngredients().size()); //gives 0
```

After calling those two above lines I get the following two logs, but `p` still has no ingredients after:

```
    Hibernate: select product0_.idProduct as idProduc1_4_0_, product0_.name as name2_4_0_, orders1_.product_idProduct as product_3_3_1_, orders1_.foodOrder_idFoodOrder as foodOrde2_3_1_, orders1_.foodOrder_idFoodOrder as foodOrde2_3_2_, orders1_.product_idProduct as product_3_3_2_, orders1_.quantity as quantity1_3_2_, foodorder2_.idFoodOrder as idFoodOr1_2_3_, foodorder2_.CustomerID as Customer2_2_3_, foodorder2_.DeliverymanID as Delivery3_2_3_, foodorder2_.RestaurantID as Restaura4_2_3_ from Product product0_ left outer join OrderDetail orders1_ on product0_.idProduct=orders1_.product_idProduct left outer join FoodOrder foodorder2_ on orders1_.foodOrder_idFoodOrder=foodorder2_.idFoodOrder where product0_.idProduct=?
Hibernate: select ingredient0_.ingredient_idProduct as ingredie2_5_0_, ingredient0_.principalProduct_idProduct as principa3_5_0_, ingredient0_.ingredient_idProduct as ingredie2_5_1_, ingredient0_.principalProduct_idProduct as principa3_5_1_, ingredient0_.quantity as quantity1_5_1_, product1_.idProduct as idProduc1_4_2_, product1_.name as name2_4_2_ from ProductComposition ingredient0_ inner join Product product1_ on ingredient0_.principalProduct_idProduct=product1_.idProduct where ingredient0_.ingredient_idProduct=?
```

However, all tries can't load the ingredients. They just return an empty list.
What am I doing wrong in this methods? 
I would prefer to keep the relationship as lazy. Also because otherwise hibernate will return `cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags` referring to Product.orders and Product.ingredients

Comment: I did a test locally, it looks okej,  here is the output:1
com.tim.jpa.test.ProductComposition@711d1a52, can you try to enable the hibernate debug log and share the output here?

Comment: @Tim what did you use? I edited the post with the hibernate's log after using hibernate.initialize

Comment: CriteriaBuilder cb = PersistOperator.getEm().getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<ProductComposition> q = cb.createQuery(ProductComposition.class);
        Root<ProductComposition> product = q.from(ProductComposition.class);
        product.fetch("principalProduct", JoinType.LEFT);
        q.select(product).where(cb.equal(product.get("principalProduct"), 41));
        List<ProductComposition> ingredients = PersistOperator.getEm().createQuery(q).getResultList();
        System.out.println(ingredients.size());
        System.out.println(ingredients.get(0).toString());

Comment: This is the way that I used, it looks no problem. Here is how does it look inside the DB (I dropped some attributes to make the test easier)                
 +----------+----------------------------+----------------------+
| quantity | principalProduct_idProduct | ingredient_idProduct |
+----------+----------------------------+----------------------+
|       10 |                         41 |                   41 |
+----------+----------------------------+----------------------+
+-----------+
| idProduct |
+-----------+
|        41 |
+-----------+

Comment: @Tim yeah you're right I didn't notice it was working because of the errors I get after when I'm trying to set them to Product p. If I do p.setIngredients(ingredients) I get "a collection with cascade= all-delete-orphan was no longer referenced". If instead I do p.addIngredient() manually I get this error when committing the transaction: "A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [model.ProductComposition#model.ProductCompositionId@28c2]". I'm trying now to solve this